# RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Error:

org.apache.spark.SparkException: **RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x)** is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

```
def computeRatio(model: MatrixFactorizationModel, test_data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Rating]): Double = {
  val numDistinctUsers = test_data.map(x => x.user).distinct().count()
  val userRecs: RDD[(Int, Set[Int], Set[Int])] = test_data.groupBy(testUser => testUser.user).map(u => {
    (u._1, u._2.map(p => p.product).toSet, model.recommendProducts(u._1, 20).map(prec => prec.product).toSet)
  })
  val hitsAndMiss: RDD[(Int, Double)] = userRecs.map(x => (x._1, x._2.intersect(x._3).size.toDouble))

  val hits = hitsAndMiss.map(x => x._2).sum() / numDistinctUsers

  return hits
}
```

I am using the method in `MatrixFactorizationModel.scala`, I have to map over users and then call the method to get the results for each user. By doing that I introduce nested mapping which I believe cause the issue:

I know that issue actually take place at:

```
val userRecs: RDD[(Int, Set[Int], Set[Int])] = test_data.groupBy(testUser => testUser.user).map(u => {
  (u._1, u._2.map(p => p.product).toSet, model.recommendProducts(u._1, 20).map(prec => prec.product).toSet)
})
```

Because while mapping over I am calling `model.recommendProducts`

Comment: What is your question?, and that problem is very very important (and it is very conceptual, otherwise then spark might be chaotic), if I am correct it's discussed in the [spark's course](https://courses.edx.org/c4x/BerkeleyX/CS190.1x/asset/CS190.1x_week2b.pdf) provided by UC Berkeley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatrixFactorizationModel` is a distributed model so you cannot simply call it from an action or a transformation. The closest thing to what you do here is something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.{MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating}

def computeRatio(model: MatrixFactorizationModel, testUsers: RDD[Rating]) = {
  val testData = testUsers.map(r => (r.user, r.product)).groupByKey
  val n = testData.count

  val recommendations = model
     .recommendProductsForUsers(20)
     .mapValues(_.map(r => r.product))

  val hits = testData
    .join(recommendations)
    .values
    .map{case (xs, ys) => xs.toSet.intersect(ys.toSet).size}
    .sum

  hits / n
}
```

Notes:

- `distinct` is an expensive operation and completely obsoletely here since you can obtain the same information from a grouped data
- instead of `groupBy` followed by projection (`map`), project first and group later. There is no reason to transfer full ratings if you want only a product ids.

Comment: There is an issue i don't think its the answer but its related to mllib someone also having the same issue on `recommendProductsForUsers `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646889/why-recommendproductsforusers-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-mllib-recommen

Comment: I think its probably related to version of mllib the method was introduce on 1.4 on the server I run 1.3 so method is not available there for it throws the not a member error

Comment: If so I am not sure if there is any reasonable solution here. If number of elements in `testUsers` is small enough to fit on a driver you can map over a local structure.

Comment: I was thinking the same, if i understand what you are saying is a do a `collect` and map over? Like i was doing? I was trying to implement recommendProductsForUsers in my code but the problem is `recommendAll` is a private method other than that all the elements are available any other solution you can think off?

Comment: Exactly. Replace `test_data: RDD[Rating]` with `test_data:  Seq[Rating]`. Regarding other options nothing sensible comes to mind. Pretty much every required method is private so without modifying source and rebuilding you won't go anywhere. Any reason to use 1.3?

Comment: cloudera cdh5.4 is using 1.3 i think, and I am not maintaining servers :( I have close to 3million users would that be issue if i do collect `val numDistinctUsers = test_data.map(x => x.user).collect`

Comment: OK, so the only reasonable approach I can think of is to use RMSE between actual and predicted ratings instead comparing actual and recommended sets. I believe that in practice it is much better choice anyway since it performs in a sensible way with low ratings.

Comment: I am already doing that this basically another metric. wonder calculating recall would encounter same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94796/discussion-between-zero323-and-null-hypothesis).