# Why recommendProductsForUsers is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, matrix-factorization

i have build recommendations system using Spark with ALS collaboratife filtering mllib

my snippet code :

```
bestModel.get
 .predict(toBePredictedBroadcasted.value)
```

evrything is ok, but i need change code for fullfilment requirement, i read from scala doc in [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel)

i need to use `def recommendProducts`

but when i tried in my code :

```
bestModel.get.recommendProductsForUsers(100)
```

and error when compile :

```
value recommendProductsForUsers is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
[error]     bestModel.get.recommendProductsForUsers(100)
```

maybe anyone can help me

thx

NB : i use Spark 1.5.0

my import :

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.{ALS, Rating, MatrixFactorizationModel}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast
```

Comment: Which version of spark are you using?

Comment: i'm using spark version 1.5.0

Comment: What is the type of bestModel?

Comment: MatrixFactorizationModel

Comment: Which one? You seem to be using the one from spark.ml

Comment: which one ? it's just matrixfactorization from ALS.train

Comment: Can you add your import to the question?

Comment: i'm sory, my mistake, i just wrong set version spark in file.sbt